# Python regex '\s' vs '\\s'

Tags: python, regex

I have simple expression `\s` and `\\s`. Both expression matches `This is Sparta!!`.

```
>>> re.findall('\\s',"This is Sparta")
[' ', ' ']
>>> re.findall('\s',"This is Sparta")
[' ', ' ']
```

I am confused here. `\` is used to escape special character and `\s` represents white space  but, how both are acting here?

Comment: You might want to use raw strings instead, since `\\` is an escape character in python strings. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't confuse python-level string-escaping and regex-level string-escaping. Since `s` is not an escapable character at python-level, the interpreter understand a string like "\s" as the two characters "\" and "s". Replace "s" with "n" (for example), and it understands it as the newline character.

```
'\s' == '\\s'
True
'\n' == '\\n'
False
```

Answer (score 2):

`\` only escapes the following character if the escaped character is valid

```
>>> len('\s')
2
>>> len('\n')
1
```

compare with

```
>>> len('\\s')
2
>>> len('\\n')
2
```